# Using regex to match certain text

Tags: regex

I try to look for this answer for a while but no luck (sorry if I could describe it well). I am still newbie with regex. I am trying to match a string with only number and a certain delimiter. For example: the patter would be 8/16/32/64/.... the number will be split by '/' with arbitrary amount of number, I could find a way to match them.
My attempt is \d+/\d+? but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What language are you using? Are you just trying to verify that the string contains nothing but numbers with a slash delimiter? Or are you trying to pull this from a string?

Comment: Split the string by `/` if you're just trying to extract numbers. But if you're trying to verify a string's format that's another story. To do that I would check if `[0-9\/]+` returns only one match.

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach would be

```
[\d/]+
```

However, this does match `////` as well as just `12345`. To match only "proper" strings:

```
\d+(/\d+)+
```

Reads digits followed by delimiter+digits repeated at least once. If trailing/leading delimiters are allowed, then

```
/?(\d+/)+\d*
```

If you're using a flavor that uses slashes to quote the regex (like javascript), you'll need to escape them:

```
/\d+(\/\d+)+/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the '/' delimiter and then test for the existence of a number

Here is some C# as an example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "8/16/32/64/";
        Console.WriteLine(text);

        TestForNum(text);
        text = "8/16/32/64/b";
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        TestForNum(text);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void TestForNum(string text)
    {
        string tmp = Regex.Replace(text, @"/", "");
        Match m = Regex.Match(tmp, @"^\d+$");
        if(m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + m.Groups[0]);
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("\tno match");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
(\d+)(\D|$)
```

[See this work](http://regex101.com/r/jK8wP4) That will split a list of digits delimited by any non digit, so `1?2!3.4` would match

If you want a specific delimiter, such as `/`:

```
(\d+)(?:/|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as possible:

```
(\d+\/?)+
```

Every digit followed by [a] slash, as many as possible. You may use `g` flag for all matches.